# Delphi TForm OnCreate gets called multiple times

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

I hope I can explain this problem decently well!

I'm trying to implement a ReWire audio device as a Delphi .dll. If you don't know what ReWire is, don't worry about it. What's important is that my code compiles into a .dll, and I get calls from the ReWire system into my .dll to open up a display, check if the display is opened, and close it again.

When I get the call to launch, I do the following:

```
  if not Assigned(form) then
    form := TMyForm.Create(nil);
  form.Show;
```

where `form` is a *global variable* inside of my Delphi library (maybe a problem?). I have hooked up `MyForm`'s `OnCreate` event to do some interesting things like prepare an array of stuff I want to work with.

So far everything's good. My form has a little button in it that opens up a `TOpenDialog`. I find that as soon as that dialog closes, somehow the `OnCreate` event is firing again in my form!

I have checked that `OnDestroy` is not being called, so I have no idea why `OnCreate` is getting called again.

Unfortunately I'm not really sure what information is relevant, but here's the call stack the first time around (when the form is first set up):

[image: First call stack]

As expected, ReWire is making a call into my .dll to Launch the Panel application, so I create my form. Great, things are looking good.

Then inside my form, I open up a little dialog, select a file, and do some operations. Out of left field, `OnCreate` is called again, and here's the call stack that time:

[image: Second call stack]

It's a crazy party of calls! Reaper (at the bottom) is the ReWire host I'm using to test my application, but I have no idea what's going on inside that stack trace because none of it is my code. Suddenly the event just gets called when I don't think it should, because `OnDestroy` wasn't even called.

The only other important thing I can think of is that if I print out the address of the `Sender`, it's *different* each time, so it's somehow getting Created again or something, but I've checked that I only call the MyForm.Create once.

Any ideas as to how this type of thing could happen?

Comment: This won't work. You've got two VCL instances. One in your exe and one in the DLL. Link it all statically into one exe. Or use packages.

Comment: Start by ditching that OnCreate logic, and see if you can get it to work at all. Then, move the logic to a new function on a WM_USER message handler that is posted on your OnShow handler. That way the user sees the form early, and can see the setup happening (no delay). This will allow you to separate the two parts, and an error in one will be easier to identify.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, everybody! The answer was similar to what @Remy Lebeau suggested, and is detailed in the comment underneath his response. I really appreciate everybody's input! I'm a bit concerned with David Heffernan's comment there -- I'm new to all of this VCL stuff, so if something else goes crazy I'll make sure to think about how to keep the VCL instances to one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first stack trace, the `OnCreate` call is preceded by a call to `TCustomForm.Create()`, which is correct behavior.  In the second stack trace, the `OnCreate` call is preceded by a call to `TObject.Create()` instead, which is not correct behavior.  That leads me to think that something in your button `OnClick` event handler is either constructing an object with a bad VMT, or is otherwise corrupting memory in general and causing a bad jump into code that just happens to be occupied by your `TForm` class.  Either way, double check your `OnClick` logic for bugs.

Comment: This is pretty close to what the problem turned out to be. I discovered it late last night (early this morning?). I had instantiated an object with the code: `my_obj := my_obj.Create` instead of `my_obj := TMyClass.Create`. Stupid mistake. Unfortunately, it's apparently *both* valid syntax and didn't cause an error/exception when it executed. As a result, all sorts of craziness was happening after that function was called on an uninitialized variable. Switching to the correct syntax fixed the problem. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check on (any)where you are setting the form variable to nil. It may be that it's being set to nil without freeing the form it's pointing to, and so next time your launch code is called it's creating another instance of the form.

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately, I've checked that the Launch call is only made once, and that the variable is not set back to `nil` after being created once.